# "error_message": "environments_environment.client_id may not be NULL"

Tags: python, django, tastypie

when i create the data through curl, i got following error.

```
"error_message": "environments_environment.client_id may not be NULL"
```

My django models are,

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % self.name
class Environment(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s:%s' % (self.client.name, self.name)
```

My Resources are,

```
class ClientResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Client.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'clients'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'delete', 'post']
        authorization = Authorization()


class EnvironmentResource(ModelResource):

    client = fields.ForeignKey(ClientResource, 'clients', full=True, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:

        queryset = Environment.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'environments'
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'delete', 'post']
        authorization = Authorization()
```

After creating client, i tried to update through the

```
curl -X POST  --data '{"client":"/api/v1/clients/1/","name":"rpcenv"}' \
   -H 'Authorization: xxxxxxxx'                                        \
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8'                   \
   http://example.com/api/v1/environments/
```

but the output result seems like,

```
"error_message": "environments_environment.client_id may not be NULL"
```

Please can any one help me to resolve this error.

Answer (score 0):

It gives `"environments_environment.client_id may not be NULL"` because

```
client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
```

It takes default null=False.So you should set the client id. or if you don't want do this,

```
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Is it possible to fix this issue in tastypie level,like     client = fields.ForeignKey(ClientResource, 'clients', full=True, null=True, blank=True)